# How to integrate this formula

Tags: calculus

I need to compute $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{2e^{2x}}{x} dx.$$
I try to use integral by parts, let $u=\frac{1}{x}$, $dv=2e^{2x}dx$, then $du= -\frac{1}{x^2}$, $v=e^{2x}$.

Then $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{2e^{2x}}{x} dx$$=$$\int_{0}^{1}u dv$$

But I meet a problem when compute $\frac{e^{2x}}{x}$ for $x$ from $0$ to $1$, since the denominator will be 0, how to solve this issue?

Actually , it is part of double integral question, original question is

$\int_{0}^{1}$$\int_{-1}^{2}$ x $e^{xy}$ dx dy, this order is more difficult than the other order, but I need to calculate it. Any help?

Comment: Why do you need to compute it in that order? By Fubini's theorem the order is not important.

Comment: have to do it in both orders

Answer (score 2):

This integral does not converge:

$$
\int_0^1 \frac{2e^{2x}}{x}\, dx \geq 2\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\, dx = + \infty.
$$

Comment: So it does not exist?

Comment: Since it is an improper integral (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral) there can be two possibilities: it can converge (in which case you may be able to compute it), or it can diverge, as it happens in this case. It is not a matter of existence.

Comment: I see, besides,  I post the original question as above.